# Identifier not found or not unique. using SafeMath for uint

Tags: solidity, truffle

I keep getting this error when I try to run my contract on truffle....(Identifier not found or not unique. Using **SafeMath** for uint). Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Node v14.19.0

Below is the **contract code**

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

    contract Token {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public name = 'Nkhokwe Token';
    string public symbol = 'Nkhokwe';
    uint256 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalsupply;

    //Track balances
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    constructor() public {
        totalsupply = 1000000 * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalsupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to import SafeMath bcz you are using older version. SafeMath is not required importing in 8 version but you are using `0.5.16` which is old.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using an old version of solidity so you need to import the SafeMath Library first. Have you imported **SafeMath** lib?

If not try to import it:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

In Solidity version 8 and beyond, the need for the SafeMath library is eliminated. Solidity 8 includes built-in checks for integer overflow and underflow, making SafeMath unnecessary. This simplifies code and enhances security.

Comment: ok i have tried updating the solidy version to 0.8.0 on both contracts but when i compile i get this error **bold (Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.8.0".
Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).)**

Comment: this is the migration.sol code `// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner = msg.sender;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "This function is restricted to the contract's owner"
    );
    _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
`

Comment: i have tried updating the truffle-config.js file `require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {

  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.0"
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    },
  },
};`

Comment: Truffle is not gonna be around. Better use other tools.

Comment: @EdwardIlemba don't update the versions unless you really don't need it, just import the safe math lib. It will do the work.